# How to view msg! logs

Tags: debug

I have `msg!` calls throughout my program, and have sent a transaction to invoke the program. And now I am trying to view these `msg!`'s.

What I have tried:

- [Solana explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=devnet) doesn't seem to show it.
- `solana logs -u devnet <my_account>` doesn't display anything.

The transaction is `4kKnHiitAz6SMjE4eJrNv3xVYLizC8sxgbXmGYKkXBsYafzLfCy33PwnTPyPBVHyUfReQJySQP91QMnZA6A8CYmm` and the signature is `4kKnHiitAz6SMjE4eJrNv3xVYLizC8sxgbXmGYKkXBsYafzLfCy33PwnTPyPBVHyUfReQJySQP91QMnZA6A8CYmm`.

Comment: Can you share any relevant code?

Comment: I am following the tutorial here https://beta.solpg.io/62b23597f6273245aca4f5b4

I am calling the program using this repo https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-movie-client/blob/main/src/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

The transaction you've referenced is just a simple system transfer, and does not invoke a custom program. If you look at the transaction on the explorer, you'll won't see any logs because the invoked program does not have any logs: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4kKnHiitAz6SMjE4eJrNv3xVYLizC8sxgbXmGYKkXBsYafzLfCy33PwnTPyPBVHyUfReQJySQP91QMnZA6A8CYmm?cluster=devnet#ix-1